# Collapse nonmissing values by group

Tags: sas

```
Name    Apr14 May14 Jun14 Aug14
John    R
Peter   G
Peter          G
Peter                 G
Louis                 R
Louis                      G
Carl                  R
Dany    R
Dany                  G
```

I need unique values but keep the values not missing like this.

```
Name    Apr14 May14 Jun14 Aug14
John    R
Peter   G      G      G
Louis                 R    G
Carl                  R
Dany    R             G
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is the update statement.  It only updates missing values with nonmissing.  We initialize it with (obs=0) since the 'base' dataset isn't actually relevant here - we're just using this to collapse things.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input (Name Apr14 May14 Jun14 Aug14) ($);
datalines;
John    R
Peter   G
Peter   .       G
Peter   .   .           G
Louis   .   .           R
Louis   .   .   .             G
Carl    .     .         R
Dany    R
Dany    .      .        G
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by name;
run;

data want;
update have(obs=0) have;
by name;
run;
```

Comment: Ha, this answer seems to be cropping up a lot at the moment